# 1st,2nd and 3rd string on my semi acoustic almost doesn’t sound through the system

Tags: guitar, strings

I am a performer and have started going through a problem where my 1st,2nd and 3rd guitar string is sounding very low that it’s impossible to hear if they even exist when I’m playing on stage. I have a semi acoustic,though the other 4th,5th and 6th string sound perfectly fine! Could this be a string problem??

Comment: We need a lot more detail. Make/model guitar, make strings, pups, amp. system?

Comment: Welcome! Agreed, please tell as much as you can about the instrument and the system. Unless there are magnetic pickups involved, this sounds like an EQ problem...

Comment: Another thing to know is has it always been like this or did it come on all of a sudden? If it did just happen was there anything that was done to the instrument, like a setup or string change or even a minor accident?

Comment: Also, when you say 1st 2nd and 3rd string, are you counting from the bottom up or top down?  Technically the 1st string is the skinniest string and tuned to high e in standard tuning and the 6th string is the fattest string that is closest to the ceiling when playing the guitar and is tuned to Low E in standard tuning.  So is it the plain steel strings that are not being amplified or the strings with winding around them (fatter)?

Comment: Yep bottom to top high e starts as no.1 yes I did change strings and this started heppening do you think it matters if the strings change from what I used to use??
Guitar is epiphone j-200 ec and it started giving that string sound problem

Comment: Note for those who closed the question: the guitar in question has piezo pickup so magnetic properties of the strings do not affect it. I'm sure you can think of a better reason to close this.